# What books do you suggest for very deep understanding of calculus and limits?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, reference-request, book-recommendation

Which books other than formal calculus books like Stewart's one that can give me deep and clear understanding of calculus, limits and functions.

I want to have a clear understanding of every thing as if I founded it myself.

If you could suggest a certain road map I would be grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a suggestion: get a book on real analysis

Comment: I recommend Hardy's *A Course of Pure Mathematics*. Spivak's *Calculus* is nice but a bit more formal.